pgf import in LaTeX not working due to matplotlib axes font
I was plotting as usual and then after saving one of my plots as a pgf and then compiling LaTeX it didn't work anymore. As far as I'm aware of, I didn't change anything it just so happen to top working.
The code I'm using to make an example plot is the following:
import matplotlib . pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib .cm as cm
import tikzplotlib
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm' # Latex font
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['cmr10']
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_mathtext'] = True


# Erzeuge eine Liste von x-Werten
x = np.linspace(-5, 10, 100)
a= [2,8,8,2]
b=[2,2,8,2]

U_1=2
U_2=8
I_1=2
I_2=8

# Berechne die entsprechenden y-Werte für die Funktion y = x
y = x

# Plotte die Funktion
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(a,b, color = 'crimson', marker='', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(U_1,I_1, color = 'green', marker='x', linestyle='',label='$(U_{1}, I_{1})$', markersize=14)
plt.plot(U_2,I_2, color = 'orange', marker='x', linestyle='',label='$(U_{1}, I_{2})$', markersize=14)
plt.plot(U_2,I_1, color = 'purple', marker='x', linestyle='',label='$(U_{2}, I_{2})$', markersize=14)

# Beschriftungen für die Achsen hinzufügen
plt.xlabel('$I$ / arbitrary units')
plt.ylabel('$U$ / arbitrary units')

# Titel für den Plot hinzufügen
plt.title('Beispiel Fit')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

# Grid hinzufügen
plt.grid(True)

# Den Plot anzeigen
plt.savefig('example.pgf', format='pgf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.show()

I tried multiple things and I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the commands
mpl.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['cmr10']
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.use_mathtext'] = True

Sure I can commen them out but then (more bovious for other plots) the axes will be in a weird font and if I have a different, let's say logarithmic scaling, it wont look like 10^{-21} like in latex and the font is different as well.
The error codes in Latex which I'm getting are
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathdefault
l.109 ...\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}$\mathdefault
{\ensuremath{-}4}$}}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathdefault
l.147 ...\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}$\mathdefault
{\ensuremath{-}2}$}}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathdefault
l.185 ...\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}$\mathdefault
{0}$}}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathdefault
l.223 ...\catcode`\%=\active\def%{\%}$\mathdefault
{2}$}}%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
...

I also posted this question here
https://stackoverflow.com/q/78504075/2777074

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78504075/2777074

Yes you’re right, I edited both entry’s

Thanks! Including the intermediate .tex file might increase your chances to get an answer.

Update: After some more researching I am now certain that the problem occurs because the pgf file uses the command '\mathdefault' which LaTex doe not know. I manually deleted all of these commands in my .pgf file and now Latex is compiling as usual without any issue.
I wrote a small .bat script
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%f in (*.pgf) do (
    set "outfile=%%~nf_temp.pgf"
    (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%l in (%%f) do (
            set "line=%%l"
            set "line=!line:\mathdefault=!"
            echo !line!
        )
    ) > "!outfile!"
    move /y "!outfile!" "%%f" > nul
)

endlocal

which deletes them automatically after the pgf file is created.
Does someone know how I can do this directly in python without the need of this extra bat file ?
